# Jenkins Node - Scripts are not stopped after performing stop operation in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I configured Jenkins Slave and created a job to run in slave.
After triggering the job , if I am stopping it in Jenkins it showing the Job has been stopped.
But in the node still script is still running.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that too. see also [JENKINS-6188](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-6188)